# Can i use my boot hard drive to install ubuntu?

Tags: boot

I have a computer that it's internal hd has died and i wasn't able to remove it, so I was wondering if I could use the same external hd that has the ubuntu boot on it to install ubuntu and actually use it? I dont have any flash drives around so its gotta be on the same external hard drive.

Thanks

Comment: If the internal HDD is dead, what could you install Ubuntu onto? Edit: oh, you mean install from the external HDD onto the external HDD, right?

Comment: yes, to the same HDD

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use External HD you have to make it bootable. So you need another computer to make it bootable and then you can install ubuntu on it.

Comment: i already did that, but i dont know how to install ubuntu to the same hd, i saw a lot of stuff about partitions but im confused in how do i do it

Comment: Where you have another computer available, the easiest method is probably going to be to boot a live session in a virtual machine, mount the HDD in the VM, then install Ubuntu on it. I'll find you a link for instructions.

Comment: @FelipeFig See [this answer on 'How do I install Ubuntu to a USB key? (without using Startup Disk Creator)'](http://askubuntu.com/a/54388/301745)